# Array<Number>: get and set Int values without casting

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin, invariance

I am building a Matrix class and want to be able to store `Number`s in a 2d Array.

```
var data: Array<Array<Number>> = Array(width, {Array(height, {0})})
```

This does not work because `Array<Number>` and `Array<Int>` are invariant.
I can make it work by using `Array<Array<out Number>>`, but the Matrix will be immutable, and I don't want that...

Casting `{0 as Int}` makes the compiler error go away, but this does not seem like a good idea. I also want to do things like addition and I noticed that it's not possible to add `Number`s:

```
var n: Number = 1
n + 1 // does not work
```

So how could I solve this problem? And why exactly can I not add two `Number`s?

Answer (score 2):

Number is an abstract class and does not define anything for addition. And since there's no defined method for adding the numbers, you can't do `numberInstane + otherNumberInstance`. You can, however, create an operator function for it:

```
infix operator fun Number.plus(other: Number) : Number{
    return when (this) {
        is Double -> this + other.toDouble()
        is Int -> this + other.toInt()
        is Long -> this + other.toLong()
        is Float -> this + other.toFloat()
        is Short -> this + other.toShort()
        is Byte ->  this + other.toByte()
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

Note that this only applies to addition. The rest of the functions would follow the same pattern, but replacing the operator (here it's `+`) and the name of the function (here it's `plus`).

---

As mer msrd0's comment, the above would result in 1 + 1.5 being 2, because it rounds down. Kotlin supports adding number types across each other, which ends up with this slightly horrid solution:

```
infix operator fun Number.plus(other: Number) : Number{

    when {
        this is Double -> {
            return when(other){
                is Double -> this + other
                is Int -> this + other
                is Long -> this + other
                is Float -> this + other
                is Short -> this + other
                is Byte ->  this + other
                else -> 0
            }
        }
        this is Int -> {
            return when(other){
                is Double -> this + other
                is Int -> this + other
                is Long -> this + other
                is Float -> this + other
                is Short -> this + other
                is Byte ->  this + other
                else -> 0
            }
        }
        this is Long -> {
            return when(other){
                is Double -> this + other
                is Int -> this + other
                is Long -> this + other
                is Float -> this + other
                is Short -> this + other
                is Byte ->  this + other
                else -> 0
            }
        }
        this is Float -> {
            return when(other){
                is Double -> this + other
                is Int -> this + other
                is Long -> this + other
                is Float -> this + other
                is Short -> this + other
                is Byte ->  this + other
                else -> 0
            }
        }
        this is Short -> {
            return when(other){
                is Double -> this + other
                is Int -> this + other
                is Long -> this + other
                is Float -> this + other
                is Short -> this + other
                is Byte ->  this + other
                else -> 0
            }
        }
        this is Byte -> {
            return when(other){
                is Double -> this + other
                is Int -> this + other
                is Long -> this + other
                is Float -> this + other
                is Short -> this + other
                is Byte ->  this + other
                else -> 0
            }
        }
        else -> return 0
    }
}
```

The nested when-statement helps autocasting the values, which is necessary since Number isn't a specific known class. There might be a better solution though, but without knowing the specific type. The extension function is mostly just auto-casting based on the type, but there can't be a single variable because it would need to be defined as a Number to accept all the types, and since there are two vars where both need proper casting based on the passed type, it ends up being slightly messy.

Comment: Ok, I see.. so I guess doing this would work, but it does not seem like a clean solution :/

Comment: @Tagas it's a slightly hackish solution, but it's the easiest option without manually casting.

Comment: While your solution might work, one might argue that `1 + 1.5` should be `2.5`, while your plus operator function would return `2` since you only check the type of `this`, not `other`

Comment: @msrd0 you're right. I've edited my answer (all though it's a kinda messy solution)